# Eclipse tasks for a generic file

Tags: eclipse, mylyn, todo

Is it possible to have tasks in Eclipse for a generic file containing text.
I'm using Eclipse to write an essay and would like to use the task mechanism so that I can get back to the unfinished parts.

For example:

```
TODO: Check if this information is up to date
```

If this can't be done automatically by leaving TODO marks, can it be done manually?

I've tried the Add task, but id doesn't let me set the location (On element, In folder, Location).

Or is it perhaps possible to map a mylyn task to a row in the text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just right-click in the Marker Bar (aka Vertical bar on the left) and select Add Task..., it will set the On Element:, In folder: and Location: fields for you.

[image]